# Web Api 2 based service doesn't work on IIS 8.5 where another similar service works properly

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, asp.net-web-api2

I have two .NET 4.5.2 Web Api services hosted in IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2. One is called CtpVin and the other is called WixTrial.

[image]

For all practical purposes, they have the same config files, global.asax files and Wix based installers. The WixTrial service works and downloads a json while CtpVin service gives a 404.

Both have this in the config file:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Here is the 404 error I get:
[image: Here is the error]

What am I doing wrong in CtpVin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. The issue was with the routes specified in the WebApiConfig.cs file.